# Using CUDA Occupancy Calculator

Tags: cuda

I am using occupancy calculator but I cannot understand how to get the Registers per thread / shared memory per block .I read the documentation.I use visual studio .So in the project properties under CUDA build rule->Command Line -> Additional Options I add --ptxas-options=-v.The program compiles fine .But i do not see any output .Can anybody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With this switch on there should be a line on the compiler output window that tells you about the number of registers and amount of shared memory.
Do you see anything at all on the compiler output window? can you copy and paste it to the question?
It should look something like

```
ptxas info : Used 3 registers, 2084+1060 bytes smem, 40 bytes cmem[0], 12 bytes cmem[1]
```

Comment: By compiler output window do you mean the debug window where I see the output of all my printfs? If yes , then 'no' I do not see anything in that window.It just prints out the time measurements i performed.

Comment: The output window is the one that shows the list of files as they are being compiled one after the other after you start building your project. It is part of the Visual Studio user interface. it has nothing to do with what you see when you run your program. You can open it by selecting "Output" from the "View" menu.

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple rule:

All the local variables like **int a, float b** etc in your kernel are stored in registers. This is only when local variables in your code remains within the limit of available registers in a multiprocessor, **[See Limits](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2010/06/09/nvidia-cuda-difference-between-fermi-and-previous-architectures/)**. However, if you declare a thousand integers like **int a[1000]** then **a** will not be stored in registers rather it will be stored in local memory (DRAM).

The amount of shared memory used in your kernel code is Shared Memory/Block. For example if you define `__shared__ float shMem[256]` then you are using 256*4(size of float) = 1024 bytes of shared memory.

The following sample code (it'll not work properly, just for example) uses **9** 32-bit-registers per thread which are: **int xIndex, yIndex, Idx, shY, shX, aLocX, aLocY** and **float t, temp**. The code uses **324 bytes** of shared memory per block, as BLOCK_DIM = 16.

```
__global__ void averageFilter (unsigned char * outImage,
                           int imageWidth,
                           int imageHeight,
                           cuviPoint2 loc){


    unsigned int xIndex = blockIdx.x * BLOCK_DIM + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int yIndex = blockIdx.y * BLOCK_DIM + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int Idx = yIndex*imageWidth + xIndex;
    float t = INC;


    if(xIndex>= imageWidth|| yIndex>=imageHeight)
        return;


    else if(xIndex==0 || xIndex== imageWidth-1 || yIndex==0 || yIndex==imageHeight-1){

          for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++)
             for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++)
                 t+= tex1Dfetch(texMem,Idx+i*imageWidth+j);
                    outImage[Idx] = t/6;

          }


    __shared__ unsigned char shMem[BLOCK_DIM+2][BLOCK_DIM+2];


    unsigned int shY = threadIdx.y + 1;
    unsigned int shX = threadIdx.x + 1;


   if (threadIdx.x==0 || threadIdx.x==BLOCK_DIM-1 || threadIdx.y==0 || threadIdx.y==BLOCK_DIM-1){


 for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++)
      for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++)
        shMem[shY+i][shX+j]=  tex1Dfetch(texMem,Idx+i*imageWidth+j);

    }
    else
    shMem[shY][shX] =  tex1Dfetch(texMem,Idx);

     __syncthreads();     



if(xIndex==0 || xIndex== imageWidth-1 || yIndex==0 || yIndex==imageHeight-1)
        return;     

  int aLocX = loc.x, aLocY = loc.y;

    float temp=INC;

      for (int i=aLocY; i<=aLocY+2; i++)
         for (int j=aLocX; j<=aLocX+2; j++)
        temp+= shMem[shY+i][shX+j];

        outImage[Idx] = floor(temp/9);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[shoosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033344/using-cuda-occupancy-calculator/5033443#5033443) is probably the easiest way to find the register and shared memory usage.  Make sure you're looking at the output pane first (select "Output" in the "View" pull-down menu) and then re-compile.  The compiler should give you ptxas info for all kernels in the output pane, like you can see in the picture below...

[image: View of ptxas compiler output in VS output window]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find this information out is to use the visual profiler or nvidia's parallel nsight.

Comment: thanks jmiloy I used profiler but as I mentioned the moment the 3 runs are completed it says 'Error displaying output' and I dont see anything.

Comment: there are many different reasons that can contribute to this error, and you should search around for solutions. It will be worth your time. (for example, adding an explicit call to cudaThreadExit() at the end of your code could help. Or, the profiler could timeout silently if the kernel takes too long. Or, if you have a scanf() at the end of the program the profiler will not work. Or if the kernel is very small it might give this error.)

Comment: Ok...so i did check most of what you have mentioned.I checked for last cuda error and it says cudaSuccess .I had the getchar thing intially but removed it and the 3 runs on the profiler complete.This is why I am even more bugged as to why it wouldnt work.