# CUDA --ptxas-options="-v" not showing any output

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cuda, nvcc

I have Visual Studio 2008 on 64-bit Windows. Trying to build the CUDA program by adding `--ptxas-options="-v"` in CUDA->Command Line->Additional Options. I still don't see the ptxas info as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310608/1961040) answer.

Here is the data in "All options" section of CUDA->Command Line section:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe"  -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include" -I"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\inc" -O0 -arch compute_10 -code compute_10 --host-compilation C++ -c -m 64 -o "x64\Release\CUDA_Dissertation.obj" -odir "x64\Release" -ext none -int real  --ptxas-options="-v" "c:\Documents and Settings\shubham\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MTP\CUDA_Dissertation\CUDA_Dissertation.vcproj"
```

Is it possible that some other flag is suppressing the ptxas flag? Or my build congiguration (Release x64) has something to with it? Or some other option to enable/disable. I tried compiling it from Command Prompt with pretty much the same command like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe"  -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include" -I"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\inc" -O0 -arch compute_10 -code compute_10 --host-compilation C++ -c -m 64 -o "x64\Release\CUDA_Dissertation.obj" -odir "x64\Release" -ext none -int real  --ptxas-options="-v" main.cu
```

This compiles with the same output as Visual Studios (warning and stuff) but no ptxas info.

Comment: Did you try `--ptxas-options=-v` without the quotation marks ?

Comment: what happens if you get rid of the `-c` switch in your manual compile?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: removing `-c` gives linking errors for the functions defined in other .cpp files.

Answer (score 1):

I have just seen such error, with toolkit 4.0 it gives proper output, with 5.0 it does not. I moved that commandline option from the global project settings to the properties of .cu file and it started to work. Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not seeing any verbose output from `--ptxas-options=-v` is that ptxas is not compiling anything.

In your nvcc invocation:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe"

...

-arch compute_10 -code compute_10

...
```

you specify your `-code` option as `-code compute_10`, which just includes a PTX architecture and not an *real* `sm_*` architecture. This means that no PTX code is being compiled into binary code by `ptxas`; the PTX code is just included as-is in the output, to be JIT compiled later.

To see ptxas info, try changing your `-code` option to `-code compute_10,sm_10` instead.

So, in your case, your nvcc invocation would be:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -ccbin      "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v4.2\include" -I"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\C\common\inc" -O0 -arch compute_10 -code compute_10,sm_10 --host-compilation C++ -c -m 64 -o "x64\Release\CUDA_Dissertation.obj" -odir "x64\Release" -ext none -int real --ptxas-options="-v" "c:\Documents and Settings\shubham\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MTP\CUDA_Dissertation\CUDA_Dissertation.vcproj"
```

Does this help?